# Orchard CMS work with MediaPickerField defined in Migrations.cs

Tags: orchardcms

MediaPickerFields still elude me.

I've defined a new Part in Migrations.cs and added a `Boolean` column and a `MediaPickerField` to the part as follows:

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ImageContentPartRecord", table =>
            table.ContentPartRecord()
            .Column("DisplayImage", DbType.Boolean));

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("ImageContentPart", builder =>
            builder
                .Attachable()
                .WithField("ImageField", fld =>
                    fld.OfType("MediaPickerField")
                    .WithDisplayName("Image")));
```

Assuming I have `ImageContentPart` and `ImageContentPartRecord` classes, how can I retrieve the data from my MediaPickerField (url, dimensions, alt text, class, etc) in my Driver and in my Part Templates (Edit / Display)?

i.e. - Parts.ImageContent.cshtml (I want to accomplish something like this):

```
<div>
     <img src="@Model.ImageField.Url" alt="@Model.ImageField.Alt" />
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After some digging, I have the solution. I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

In my Display Driver method, I make sure to pass my `ImageContentPart`(`part`) when building the `ContentShape`:

```
return ContentShape("Parts_ImageContent", () =>
            shapeHelper.Parts_ImageContent(
                Content: part));
```

Then in my Template View, I leverage the dynamic nature of Orchard's architecture to consume my `MediaPickerField`. To do this, you access the `.ContentItem` property on your part, then leaning on dynamics, chain the part name (`.ImageContentPart`) and then the field name (`.ImageContent`) to access the field.

```
@{
    // Attempting to access MediaPickerField named 'ImageContent'
    var image = Model.Content.ContentItem.ImageContentPart.ImageContent;

    // Leaning on Orchard dynamics to access properties of the field
    var url = image.Url;
}

<img src="@url" alt="@T(image.AlternateText)" />
```

Here is an exhaustive list of MediaPickerField properties from `\\Orchard.Fields\Views\Fields\MediaPicker.cshtml`:

```
@* 
    Alternate Text: @Model.ContentField.AlternateText
    Class: @Model.ContentField.Class
    Style: @Model.ContentField.Style
    Alignment: @Model.ContentField.Alignment
    Width: @Model.ContentField.Width
    Height: @Model.ContentField.Height
    Url: @Model.ContentField.Url


    You can also display an image using this example, and add the attributes you need:
    <img src="@Href(Model.ContentField.Url)" />
*@
```

Hopefully, if you stumble upon a similar problem, this will help out!